# Is there a way to remove or hide a part of an image with css or jquery

Tags: html, css, sass, background-image, crop

I am making a website which has a certain background image. When it changes screen size i need the middle part of an image do be removed so the graphic would look slimmer . Here is the picture.

This is how it is now :

[image]

This is how i need it when the screen is changed to tablet :

[image]

My html :

```
<section class="hero" style="background-image: url(./images/hero.png)">
<header class="header">
  <img src="./images/logo.png" alt="Logo image" class="logo">
  <div class="shape hamburger">
    <!-- <a href="javascript:;" class="line-shape"><span class="hide">Hamburger icon</span></a> -->
    <a class="line-shape" href="javascript:;"><span></span><span class="hide">Hamburger icon</span></a>
    <span class="shape-txt" >MENU</span>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-2 offset-2 col-2-t offset-2-t">
    <h1 class="section-title">
      Living our values
      Transforming our business
    </h1>
    <p class="txt">
      UDG Healthcare plc</br>
      Annual Report and Accounts 2015
    </p>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="padded"><span class="s s-down-arrow"><span class="hide">download</span></span>Download Full Report <span class="no-under">(PDF, 2.5 MB)</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
<span class="above-btn">Explore our year</br>
    in review</span>
<button type="button" class="down"><img src="./images/down.png" alt="Move to the top content"><span class="s s-down-arrow btn-arrow"><span class="hide">Move Down</span></span></button>
```

My css :

```
.hero {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: $hero-bg-cream;
  overflow: hidden;

  .row {
    margin: 0;
  }

  h1 {
    padding: 106px 0 7px;
    line-height: 1.15;
    word-spacing: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    width: 70%;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: $grey;
  }

  .txt {
    line-height: 19px;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
    color: $grey;
  }

  .padded {
    padding-bottom: 421px;
  }

  .s-down-arrow {
    &:last-child {
      left: -38px;
      color: $grey;
      top: 0;
    }
  }

  .above-btn {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    color: $grey;
  }

  .down {
    transform: translateX(13%);
  }

  @include breakpoint (tablet) {
    h1 {
      font-size: 29px;
      padding: 217px 0 7px;
    }

    .txt {
      padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .padded {
      padding-bottom: 308px;
    }

    .down {
      transform: translateX(10%);
    }
  }
}
```

I guess I would need to remove the right part of the image or something like that ?

Comment: It is hard to tell from your screenshots what you actually want to change and where ... or even which is the image in question to begin with, the face of the woman, the multi-colored ring made up of triangles, or both?

Comment: @misorude So when the screen goes from desktop to tablet , the space of the bg-image that is between the woman and the ring needs to get smaller . The woman and the ring need to get closer to each other. Hope it makes sense ..

Comment: Well then it would make most sense that you use two separate background images, one for each, so that you can position them closer together or further apart …

Comment: So the only solution would be to change the image every time screen changes .. that is exactly what i didn't want to do :D

Comment: Nobody said anything about “every time” … You use two background images, one for the lady, one for the shape-thingy – and then you manipulate the background _position_ (and maybe size) between your breakpoints …

Comment: @misorude I am not sure I understand using two bg images .. U mean i will use two same images and than position them one in front of the other ?

Comment: No, two different images, containing one of your “objects” each - so that you can control the space between them via the position of those two background images.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the solution was to make the `background-size: auto;`

Comment: This won't fix it on all screen sizes. Background-size: auto; just sets the background size to the original size of the image.

Comment: Ah yeah I just saw that... I need it to be a bit smaller bit it is just the same size ..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this here in HTML :

```
<section class="hero" style="background-image: url(./images/hero.png); background-size: 100% 100%;">
```

Or here, in CSS

```
.hero {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-color: $hero-bg-cream;
  overflow: hidden;

  .row {
    margin: 0;
  }
```

Comment: Doesn't really work.. the image just go in the left corner and goes to really small

Comment: @BojanKolano I've amended my solution.

Comment: This streched the image and positioned it at the top. I did manage to do something with it with bg-position x and y . I do get what I wanted but now I have some empty space in the top

Comment: background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 161% 609%;
    background-color: #e5eaea;
    background-position-x: -56px;
    background-position-y: 37px;
    overflow: hidden;

Comment: Thats what i used